# Scraping members ids from a guild, and putting them on a list

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to do a command that returns all the members ID in a guild, I've been doing this so far:

```
themembers = []
@client.command()
async def getids(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for members in guild.members:
        try:
            themembers.append(members.id)
        except:
            pass
    print(themembers)
```

But this code only gives me the ID of the bot account; how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Enable intents, see: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Intents are enabled in your [application](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

[image: Make sure both options are enabled]

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=("!"), case_insensitive=True, guild_subscriptions=True, intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    member_list = []
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            member_list.append({member.name:member.id})
    print(member_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(list(mab(lambda i: i.id, bot.get_all_members())))
```